# JTextField not visible until mouse over

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am trying to make a simple calculator program with Java. When I added a `JTextField` however it made all the button and the field itself invisible until I hover over it. If I comment out the text field everything goes back to normal and all the button are visible.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Calculator extends JFrame {

// Numbers
JButton btn_zero;
JButton btn_one;
JButton btn_two;
JButton btn_three;
JButton btn_four;
JButton btn_five;
JButton btn_six;
JButton btn_seven;
JButton btn_eight;
JButton btn_nine;

// Operators
JButton btn_add;
JButton btn_subtract;
JButton btn_multiply;
JButton btn_divide;
JButton btn_equals;
JButton btn_decimal;
JButton btn_pm;
JButton btn_clear;

// Panel
JPanel buttonPanel;

// Dimensions
final int WIDTH = 340;
final int HEIGHT = 500;

public Calculator() {
    // Characteristics of frame
    super("Calculator");
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Insets frameInsets = getInsets();
    int frameWidth = WIDTH + (frameInsets.left + frameInsets.right);
    int frameHeight = HEIGHT + (frameInsets.top + frameInsets.bottom);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(frameWidth, frameHeight));
    //setLayout(null);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);


    // Add values to all buttons
    btn_zero = new JButton("0");

    btn_one = new JButton("1");
    btn_two = new JButton("2");
    btn_three = new JButton("3");
    btn_four = new JButton("4");
    btn_five = new JButton("5");
    btn_six = new JButton("6");
    btn_seven = new JButton("7");
    btn_eight = new JButton("8");
    btn_nine = new JButton("9");
    btn_add = new JButton("+");
    btn_subtract = new JButton("-");
    btn_multiply = new JButton("×");
    btn_divide = new JButton("÷");
    btn_equals = new JButton("=");
    btn_decimal = new JButton(".");
    btn_pm = new JButton("±");
    btn_clear = new JButton("C");

    // Adds the panel
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setSize(new Dimension(frameWidth, frameHeight));
    buttonPanel.setLayout(null);

    // Textfield
    JTextField AnswerBox = new JTextField ("");
    AnswerBox.setBounds(0, 0, 320, 70);
    buttonPanel.add(AnswerBox); 

    //Buttons
    btn_decimal.setBounds(70, 100, 50, 50);
    buttonPanel.add(btn_decimal);
    btn_pm.setBounds(130, 100, 50, 50);
    buttonPanel.add(btn_pm);
    btn_clear.setBounds(190, 100, 50, 50);
    buttonPanel.add(btn_clear);
    btn_add.setBounds(250, 100, 50, 50);
    buttonPanel.add(btn_add);
    btn_subtract.setBounds(250, 160, 50, 50);
    buttonPanel.add(btn_subtract);
    btn_multiply.setBounds(250, 220, 50, 50);
    buttonPanel.add(btn_multiply);
    btn_divide.setBounds(250, 280, 50, 50);
    buttonPanel.add(btn_divide);
    btn_equals.setBounds(10, 350, 290, 50);
    buttonPanel.add(btn_equals);
    btn_zero.setBounds(190, 160, 50, 170);
    buttonPanel.add(btn_zero);
    btn_one.setBounds(10, 160, 50, 50);
    buttonPanel.add(btn_one);
    btn_two.setBounds(70, 160 , 50, 50);
    buttonPanel.add(btn_two);
    btn_three.setBounds(130, 160, 50, 50);
    buttonPanel.add(btn_three);
    btn_four.setBounds(10, 220, 50, 50);
    buttonPanel.add(btn_four);
    btn_five.setBounds(70, 220, 50, 50);
    buttonPanel.add(btn_five);
    btn_six.setBounds(130, 220, 50, 50);
    buttonPanel.add(btn_six);
    btn_seven.setBounds(10, 280, 50, 50);
    buttonPanel.add(btn_seven);
    btn_eight.setBounds(70, 280, 50, 50);
    buttonPanel.add(btn_eight);
    btn_nine.setBounds(130, 280, 50, 50);
    buttonPanel.add(btn_nine);

    buttonPanel.setVisible(true);
    add(buttonPanel);

}
}
```

Also the code is also right now just showing the buttons of the calculator, and not actually doing anything, because I want to focus on fixing this bug.

Comment: Take `setVisible(true);` and put it at the end of the constructor.  Attentively, call `revalidate` and `repaint` at the end of the method

Comment: 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) See also this [calculator example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556).  It uses `ScriptEngine` to evaluate the expression in the text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [`revalidate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#revalidate--) after you add all the widgets to recalculate the layout of the container (in your case a `JFrame`):

```
buttonPanel.setVisible(true);
add(buttonPanel);
revalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `revalidate()` at the end would work or you can simply put

```
setVisible(true)
```

to the end of your constructor.